# xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'macosx'

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal

Whenever I open up a new terminal this message appears (it happened once I installed Mojave on my  OSX machine).

What can I do to fix this?

```
Last login: Wed Sep 25 13:28:13 on ttys006
2019-09-25 13:37:37.543 xcodebuild[39765:4976662] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DVTKitDFRSupport” couldn’t be loaded.}, dyldError = dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 0): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
2019-09-25 13:37:37.544 xcodebuild[39765:4976662] [MT] DVTPlugInExtensionFaulting: Failed to fire fault for extension Xcode.DVTKitDFRSupport.Initializer: Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 "Loading a plug-in failed." UserInfo={DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 0): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in “com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport” at path “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin” could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff01a91f700 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DVTKitDFRSupport” couldn’t be loaded.}}}
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception **
Uncaught Exception: Error getting value for key 'initializationClass' of extension 'Xcode.DVTKitDFRSupport.Initializer' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport'
Stack:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2   -[DVTExtension valueForKey:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  3   _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
  4   _IDEInitializePlugIns (in IDEFoundation)
  5   IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
  6   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
  7  0x000000010d0c5202 (in xcodebuild)
  8   start (in libdyld.dylib)

2019-09-25 13:37:38.004 xcodebuild[39767:4976683] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DVTKitDFRSupport” couldn’t be loaded.}, dyldError = dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 0): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
2019-09-25 13:37:38.004 xcodebuild[39767:4976683] [MT] DVTPlugInExtensionFaulting: Failed to fire fault for extension Xcode.DVTKitDFRSupport.Initializer: Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 "Loading a plug-in failed." UserInfo={DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 0): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in “com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport” at path “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin” could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8d715b7e00 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DVTKitDFRSupport” couldn’t be loaded.}}}
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception **
Uncaught Exception: Error getting value for key 'initializationClass' of extension 'Xcode.DVTKitDFRSupport.Initializer' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport'
Stack:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2   -[DVTExtension valueForKey:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  3   _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
  4   _IDEInitializePlugIns (in IDEFoundation)
  5   IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
  6   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
  7  0x000000010d511202 (in xcodebuild)
  8   start (in libdyld.dylib)

xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'macosx'
(µ_env) jespinozlt-osx:~ jespinoz$
```

It also happens when I run the following:

```
(µ_env) jespinozlt-osx:~ jespinoz$ xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx
2019-09-25 12:55:13.253 xcodebuild[38278:4955104] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DVTKitDFRSupport” couldn’t be loaded.}, dyldError = dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 0): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
2019-09-25 12:55:13.253 xcodebuild[38278:4955104] [MT] DVTPlugInExtensionFaulting: Failed to fire fault for extension Xcode.DVTKitDFRSupport.Initializer: Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 "Loading a plug-in failed." UserInfo={DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 0): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in “com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport” at path “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin” could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe3f4f48820 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DVTKitDFRSupport” couldn’t be loaded.}}}
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception **
Uncaught Exception: Error getting value for key 'initializationClass' of extension 'Xcode.DVTKitDFRSupport.Initializer' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport'
Stack:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2   -[DVTExtension valueForKey:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  3   _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
  4   _IDEInitializePlugIns (in IDEFoundation)
  5   IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
  6   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
  7  0x0000000103212202 (in xcodebuild)
  8   start (in libdyld.dylib)

2019-09-25 12:55:13.712 xcodebuild[38279:4955120] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DVTKitDFRSupport” couldn’t be loaded.}, dyldError = dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 0): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
2019-09-25 12:55:13.713 xcodebuild[38279:4955120] [MT] DVTPlugInExtensionFaulting: Failed to fire fault for extension Xcode.DVTKitDFRSupport.Initializer: Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 "Loading a plug-in failed." UserInfo={DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 0): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in “com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport” at path “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin” could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa596467520 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DVTKitDFRSupport, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DVTKitDFRSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DVTKitDFRSupport” couldn’t be loaded.}}}
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception **
Uncaught Exception: Error getting value for key 'initializationClass' of extension 'Xcode.DVTKitDFRSupport.Initializer' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.IDE.DVTKitDFRSupport'
Stack:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2   -[DVTExtension valueForKey:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  3   _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
  4   _IDEInitializePlugIns (in IDEFoundation)
  5   IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
  6   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
  7  0x000000010adef202 (in xcodebuild)
  8   start (in libdyld.dylib)

xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'macosx'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall xcode through the App Store

Answer (score 7):

This command might help you as well

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by running the following command:

```
xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```